# Class pointers in Parse queries

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have two classes in a Parse app: `Catalogue`, and `CatalogueItem`. The `Catalogue` just has an issue number at the moment, and the `CatalogueItem` has a pointer back to the `Catalogue` it comes from.

If I have a restful endpoint of `/catalogues/` for the data and I supply a number then my intention is to get back a JSON object with the catalogue as the root, and the items as an array of that object.

At the moment, I have a query set up like this:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(CatalogueItem)
query.include("catalogue")

var issueQuery = new Parse.Query(Catalogue)
issueQuery.equalTo("issue", issue)

query.matchesQuery("catalogue", issueQuery)
return query.find()
```

What I get back is an array of items for that catalogue, but each item contains the catalogue which it's associated with, meaning there's a lot of duplicated data.

I could just rearrange the data before returning it, but it seems like I should be able to arrange a query that says "Get me a catalogue and all its items".

Any helpful pointers to the docs with an admonishing "Have you read this bit recently?" would be gratefully appreciated!